# Как добавить на поле черные шашки и определить правила взятия?

Tags: рекурсия, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста.

> Задание. На шашечном поле в произвольном порядке расставлены шашки. Для выбранной пользователем белой шашки определить все ее возможные ходы. Учесть, что за один шаг белая шашка может сбить несколько черных шашек.

Я не знаю, как добавить на это поле чёрные шашки, как заставить белую шашку бить чёрные шашки и сделать проверку на то, чтобы белая шашка не била другие белые шашки...

Это то, что я смог написать...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#define LEN 8

char desk[LEN][LEN];

void xod(int x, int y)
{
    if (x + 1 < LEN && y + 1 < LEN) {
        if (desk[y + 1][x + 1] == 'o') {
            if (x + 2 < LEN && y + 2 < LEN && desk[y + 2][x + 2] == '_') {
                desk[y + 1][x + 1] = '_';
                xod(x + 2, y + 2);
            }
        } else
            xod(x + 1, y + 1);
    }
    if (x - 1 >= 0 && y + 1 < LEN) {
        if (desk[y + 1][x - 1] == 'o') {
            if (x - 2 >= 0 && y + 2 < LEN && desk[y + 2][x - 2] == '_') {
                desk[y + 1][x - 1] = '_';
                xod(x - 2, y + 2);
            }
        } else
            xod(x - 1, y + 1);
    }
    if (x + 1 < LEN && y - 1 >= 0) {
        if (desk[y - 1][x + 1] == 'o') {
            if (x + 2 < LEN && y - 2 >= 0 && desk[y - 2][x + 2] == '_') {
                desk[y - 1][x + 1] = '_';
                xod(x + 2, y - 2);
            }
        }
        if (x - 1 >= 0 && y - 1 >= 0) {
            if (desk[y - 1][x - 1] == 'o') {
                if (x - 2 >= 0 && y - 2 >= 0 && desk[y - 2][x - 2] == '_') {
                    desk[y - 1][x - 1] = '_';
                    xod(x - 2, y - 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int x, y;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        cout << i + 1 << " ";
    cout << "x y" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < LEN; j++) {
            desk[i][j] = (rand() % 2 == 0) ? '_' : 'o';
            cout << desk[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "  " << i + 1 << endl;
    }
    cout << "Enter coordinates: ";
    cin >> x >> y;
    xod(x - 1, y - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        cout << i + 1 << " ";
    cout << "x y" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < LEN; j++) {
            cout << desk[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "  " << i + 1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: подпиши комментарии что делает тот или иной блок (на твой взгляд)
что является б\ч шашкой что б\ч дамкой  пример: этот блок циклов делает тото... и опиши что именно ты сделал... (тут телепатов нет, а документацией ты поясняешь свою логику)

Comment: А обязательно через функцию всё это делать?
Нельзя создать классы?

типа 
int поле[8][8];

class шашка
{
public:
bool проверка_возможности_хода(int x , int y);
bool ход(int x , int y);
bool захват_шашки(int x , int y);
bool на_поле_противник(int x , int y);
bool поле_пустое(int x , int y);
void стать_дамкой(int x , int y);
}

Answer (score 1):

Фигня какая-то.
По пунктам.

1. Почти правильно сделана расстановка шашек. Действительно, получается три типа клеток: свободная, занятая белой шашкой, занятая черной шашкой. Можно просто обозначить их разными символами в массиве, обозначающем доску. Расставлять шашки рандомом, но учесть, что кол-во черных и белых шашек ограничено. В изначальной позиции их на доске 8х8 должно быть 12 белых и 12 черных, но никто не мешает играть на досках других размеров и с другим кол-вом шашек. Напоминаю, что шашки располагаются СТРОГО на клетках одного цвета: или белых, или черных. Думаю на каких точно не столь принципиально.
2. Понятно, что шашка может ходить в нескольких направлениях. А именно: на свободные клетки по диагонали вперед, через клетку с шашкой врага по диагонали, если за ней есть свободное место, *со взятием шашки противника*. С дамками пока не будем разбираться. *Назад шашки "мирными" ходами не ходят!* Только вперед! В случае, если шашка может взять шашку противника, она ее всегда берет. Поэтому если есть вариант походить без взятия шашки противника, мы его не рассматриваем. Чтоб отсечь эту ситуацию придется ввести еще одну переменную-флаг.
3. Действительно нужно делать рекурсией. Но! При анализе следующего хода нужно сохранять старую позицию. Либо сохранять историю ходов и при возврате назад возвращать исходную ситуацию. Навскидку этого здесь не увидел.